# emacs helm M-x: how to jump to the list of historical command

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

When I run M-x to open helm, it displays 2 lists, one is the list about the ALL command matching the pattern, another list is the hisotrial. How to quickly jump to the historical one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `C-o` to switch between Helm sources (in your case jump to the historical one).

After `helm Mx` shows up, you can type `C-c ?` to display the numerous available bindings.

In my setup I bind `M-o` to `helm-previous-source`, so I use `C-o`, `M-o`, to navigate up/down sources, in addition to sources cycling `(setq helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source t)`.